# What's wrong with this div?

Tags: html, css

I have a page [here](http://daddariowebdesign.com/pedjasfriend/).

Please look at the source and tell me why the nav div is not displayed within the header div.

Comment: You should edit your post to include the code here, in case the link goes out of date in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating elements do not apply height to their container. You either need to:

- Add an element with `clear: both;` after the floats, OR
- Add `overflow:hidden;` to the containing element, OR
- Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left` [Most recommended by me]